# One to one mapping of two lists and form dataframe

Tags: pandas, list, dataframe

I've list of elements in two lists:

```
list1 = [['a','b','c'],['a','d'],['a','f','c']]
list2 = [['S1','S2','S3'],['S1','S3'],['S1','S2','S3']]
```

I want to map these two lists in a data-frame, with a specific way that if the value is present in list 1, it should make an entry into the data-frame otherwise print null or 0

```
S1   S2   S3
a     b   c
a     0   d
a     f   c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just concatenate with list comprehension:

```
(pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([a], columns=b) 
            for a,b in zip(list1,list2)],
          ignore_index=True)
   .fillna(0)
)
```

Output:

```
  S1 S2 S3
0  a  b  c
1  a  0  d
2  a  f  c
```

Comment: Thank you. @Quang Hoang

Answer (score 0):

Zip the lists, then zip the elements of the lists.

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records([dict(zip(*z)) for z in zip(list2, list1)]).fillna(0)

  S1 S2 S3
0  a  b  c
1  a  0  d
2  a  f  c
```